# How to Convert Special character in URL format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Api does not accept special character it thoroughgoing error as access-controller allow origin does not accept
My File Name is `Hello{#$^%.net}.pdf`

**My Url Format Like This**

```
 http://localhost:5300/api/Insert/DeleteRec/1-1920-9/36/Hello%7B#$^%.net}/pdf
```

**My Angular Code**

```
fac.DeleteRecFromTemp = function (EnqId, UId, FileName,exten) {
        var fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(FileName));
        return $http({
            url: hostapiUrl + 'Inser/DeleteRec/'+EnqId+"/"+UId+"/" +fixedstring+"/"+exten,
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        })
    }
```

Please Help me how can i convert that url into my browser url

Comment: @itdoesntwork its converting into Url Encode but im getting cors Issue please Help me How can i overcome this issue

Comment: does the request work using postman?

Comment: In Postamn im getting as A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).

Comment: try making the request using the encoded uri.

Comment: @itdoesntwork` Tq for your ans its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
url = encodeURI(url)
```

Comment: @willian Tran its Converting into hash code but im getting Cors Issue

Comment: You may also want to take a look to `escape(string)` and `unescape(string)` functions.